# Gnuplot Postscript Special Characters Math Equation

Tags: gnuplot, special-characters, postscript

I`d like to write the math stuff into a plot using gnuplot 5:

[image]

I am using the `terminal postscript enhanced` because as far as I know this terminal is the only only capable of doing such things.
I used this code:

```
set label 1 at 400,200 '{/Symbol=50\362@_{/=15 350}^{/=15\154}}' front
```

This gets me everything except the subscribed `average`under the lambda symbol.
I tried everything with `{,}`and so on but I think I missing the part where I can escape the `/Symbol`Style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many terminals support enhanced text, not only the `postscript` terminal.

In order to use another font than `/Symbol` for the subscript you could change the font explicitely to a different one for this. However, a better approach is to change the nesting so that `/Symbol` affects only two parts:

```
set label 1 at 0,0 '{/=50{/Symbol \362}@_{/=15 350}^{/=15{/Symbol \154}_{/=10 average}}' front
plot x
```

Output with gnuplot 5.0 with `wxt` is

[image]

If you're using the `postscript` terminal anyway, you could give a try to the `epslatex` terminal (or `cairolatex`):

```
set terminal epslatex standalone color colortext
set output 'equation.tex'
set label 1 at -5,5 '$\displaystyle\int_{350}^{\lambda_{\mathrm{average}}}$'
plot x

set output
system('latex equation.tex')
system('dvips equation.dvi')
system('ps2pdf equation.ps')
```

[image]